# How to add custom Patterns

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a referral system in my Android app with codes that look like this :  `####-####-####`

I know how to do for the Patterns of the email address I code you below

```
private boolean checkEmail() {
        String email = email_tv.getText().toString();
        if (!email.isEmpty() && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            checkPassword(email);
            return true;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Vérifiez votre email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This `Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` checks if the Text corresponds to a type of email address

**I would like my Pattern to look like this ####-####-####, know how to do it? If you have another method I want it!**

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this pattern : `\w\w\w\w-\w\w\w\w-\w\w\w\w` and this good web page : https://regex101.com/

[image]

Comment: sorry for my delay in replying, thank you very much for your help